# How to make a Golang custom SSH server openable by Vscode remote feature

Tags: docker, go, ssh, vscode-remote

I'm trying to make a tool that makes docker containers automatically sshable without modifying the containers themselves. I run the code below to spin up a Golang ssh server outside the container which directs requests to the container's bash:

```
import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/creack/pty"
    "github.com/gliderlabs/ssh"
)
func setWinsize(f *os.File, w, h int) {
    syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_IOCTL, f.Fd(), uintptr(syscall.TIOCSWINSZ),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&struct{ h, w, x, y uint16 }{uint16(h), uint16(w), 0, 0})))
}

func main() {
    ssh.Handle(func(s ssh.Session) {
        cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "-it", "nongpu_sam_test_sshd_container", "bash")
        _, winCh, _ := s.Pty()
        
            f, err := pty.Start(cmd)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            go func() {
                for win := range winCh {
                    setWinsize(f, win.Width, win.Height)
                }
            }()
            go func() {
                io.Copy(f, s) // stdin
            }()
            io.Copy(s, f) // stdout
            cmd.Wait()
        
    })

    log.Fatal(ssh.ListenAndServe(":2217", nil))
}
```

It works fine to SSH in via command, but when I open with Vscode remote - it says "Failed to parse remote port from server output". Is there something I need to send back to make vscode connect successfully?
thanks in advance for any help :)

I also tried just running the system bash instead of the container's bash and that still fails.

Comment: What's the library your using to implement the ssh server handle in go ?

Comment: This one: github.com/gliderlabs/ssh